# Missing :endfunction error for vim function

Tags: vim

In my vimrc file I am trying to write a function that take in two lines numbers as arguments and then comments out all the lines in that range. I am using a substitute for the start of the line '^' and replacing it with '#' which works fine when I call from outside a function. For the function I have this so far:

`function Comment(line1, line2)
      a:line1,a:line2s/^/#/g
endfunction`

This is not working though and I am getting an error when I try to start Vim saying 'Missing :endfunction'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your command:

```
a:line1,a:line2s/^/#/g
```

Some parts are variables (`a:line1` and `a:line2`). They need to be evaluated. To do so, you can wrap every part of your command inside a string, except the variables, then concatenate all the parts with the dot operator, and finally pass the result to the command `:execute` to execute it as a regular Ex command:

```
execute a:line1.','.a:line2.'s/^/#/g'
```

If you need a command to call it, you could try this one:

```
function! Comment(line1, line2)
    execute a:line1.','.a:line2.'s/^/#/'
endfunction

command! -range=% Comment call Comment(<line1>,<line2>)
```

It defines the `:Comment` command which calls the function with the same name. It accepts a range, because it's defined with the `-range` attribute. If you don't provide a range to the command, it will use the whole buffer, because `%` (=`1,$`) is defined as the default range. See `:h user-commands` for more info.

To use the command, you could visually select some lines, then execute:

```
:'<,'>Comment
```

To use the function, assuming you wanted to comment the lines whose address are between 10 and 20, you could execute:

```
:call Comment(10,20)
```

---

It's not linked to your issue, but if you don't add a bang to the keyword `function`, every time you will source your script, you'll have the error:

```
E122: Function Comment already exists, add ! to replace it
```

Same thing for the command, you probably want to add a bang after the keyword `command`, otherwise you'll have the error:

```
E174: Command already exists: add ! to replace it
```

Comment: I've tried doing this and when I try to run my Comment function I get an error saying 'E488: Trailing characters'. I think since we've put the expression into a string do the special characters have to be escaped?

Comment: @user2802557 I don't have this error when I execute this function, could you post in your question the exact code that you last tried?

Comment: @user2802557 To call the function to comment the first 3 lines of your file (as an example), try to execute `:call Comment(1,3)`. I've edited the answer to add more information about how calling the function and the command.

Comment: Using the command `:Comment` will be shorter, since it's not a function, and thus you won't have to use `:call` to call it. If you want shorter than that, you probably need a mapping to define a custom operator. See `:h g@` for more information, and/or read the chapters 32 to 34 of `Learn Vimscript the Hard Way`. Here's the url of the 1st relevant chapter: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/32.html